# Sum of same values in ruby hash

Tags: ruby, hash

everybody. 
I have hash for example

```
{-2=>"a", -1=>"c", 1=>"a", 3=>"a", 49=>"a", -43=>"ab", 5=>"ab"}
```

There can be equal values. My task is to sum keys where values are equal. Result:

```
{51=>"a", -1=>"c", -38=>"ab"}
```

How can I do this?

```
hash.group_by{|key,val| val}
```

Gives awful result.

Comment: What's the expected result for `{ 1 => "a", 2 => "a", 3 => "b" }`?

Comment: {  3 => "a", 3 => "b" }

Comment: Your expected result is invalid, you cannot have duplicate keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
hash = {-2=>"a", -1=>"c", 1=>"a", 3=>"a", 49=>"a", -43=>"ab", 5=>"ab"}

hash.reduce({}) do |memo, (k,v)| 
  memo[v] ||= 0
  memo[v] += k
  memo
end.invert

# => {51=>"a", -1=>"c", -38=>"ab"}
```

`reduce` - lets you build up a new value by iterating over the values of a collection, in this case `hash`. See the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) for more.

`invert` - swaps the keys and values of a hash. See the [docs](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-invert) for more.

Other ways to do this:

```
hash.reduce(Hash.new(0)) { |memo, (k,v)| memo[v] += k; memo }.invert
```

Comment: You should use `each_with_object` instead of `reduce` with 2 statements.

Comment: yeah, I'm stuck in my ways :)

Comment: Also, I know it's what OP seems to want, but `invert` could delete data if there are two strings with the same sums.

Comment: That is worth noting!

Answer (score 0):

```
h = {-2=>"a", -1=>"c", 1=>"a", 3=>"a", 49=>"a", -43=>"ab", 5=>"ab"}
```

then

```
h.group_by(&:last).each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| h[v.map(&:first).sum] = k }
  #=> {51=>"a", -1=>"c", -38=>"ab"}
```

but that would be crazy as it relies on the sums being unique. (Recall that hashes have unique keys.) Suppose

```
h = {-54=>"a", -1=>"c", 1=>"a", 3=>"a", 49=>"a", -43=>"ab", 5=>"ab"}
```

then

```
h.group_by(&:last).each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| h[v.map(&:first).sum] = k }
  #=> {-1=>"c", -38=>"ab"}
```

as `-1=>"a"` is overwritten by `-1=<"c"`. I doubt that this is wanted.

It would be better to save the contents of `h` in an array:

```
a = [[-2, "a"], [-1, "c"], [-1, "a"], [49, "a"], [-43, "ab"],  [5, "ab"]]
```

(as it permits duplicate values of the integers--here `-1`) and then compute

```
a.group_by(&:last).each_with_object({}) { |(e,ar),h| h[e] = ar.map(&:first).sum }
  #=> {"a"=>46, "c"=>-1, "ab"=>-38}
```

Note that (for the original value of `h`)

```
h.group_by(&:last)
  #=> {"a"=>[[-2, "a"], [1, "a"], [3, "a"], [49, "a"]],
  #    "c"=>[[-1, "c"]], "ab"=>[[-43, "ab"], [5, "ab"]]}
```

and `v.map(&:first).sum` could be replaced with

```
v.reduce(0) { |t,(n,_)| t+n }
```